# User Complete input Value in command prompt via bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a bat file for schedule shut down in Windows. It is pretty easy and shutdown -s -t 00 complete the work (00 is seconds and changeable).

I am attempting to go through command prompt and again it is easy as the same command works effectively.

But I am trying that when Command prompt shows "shutdown -s -t 00" users can edit OO. And after entering a new value by users replacing 00 the whole command (shutdown -s -t 00) may work. Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

```
:: Prompt the user, and store their input in variable T_VAL
set /P T_VAL="How long to shutdown?"

:: Call the shutdown command, putting the user-input in place of %T_VAL%
shutdown -s -t %T_VAL%
```

If the user enters `05`, then the command should be:
`shutdown -s -t 05`

***Warning:***
There is no safety/security here.

If the user enters `foo & format C:`
then the resulting command will be:

```
shutdown -s -t foo & format C:
```

Causing:

```
Error: foo is not a valid value for shutdown.
Ok: Reformatting your drive, all data will be lost.
```

*How much do you trust your users?*